# WPF - Weird scrollbars behavior in TabItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, tabcontrol, scrollviewer

I have following code:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="145" Width="156">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tabTemplate">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock>x</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>x</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>x</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>x</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>x</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>x</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>x</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Tab1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=tabTemplate}"/>
            <TabItem Header="Tab2" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=tabTemplate}"/>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What is weird is the behavior of scrollbars - if I scroll down on the first tab and switch to second tab, the scrollbar is down too - position of the scrollbars is synchronized when the tab items have the same data templates. Do you know about any solution of this issue?

In addition, when I alter the code and make two data templates (one for each tab), the scrollbars are not preserving their position at all - that means if I scroll down on tab1, switch to tab2 and to tab1 again, the scrollbar is on default position. Any solution of this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable the `DataTemplate` to create separate instances for each usage, just set the `x:Shared` attribute to `False`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="tabTemplate" x:Shared="False">
```

That will cause your second issue, which is preserving the UI when the tab changes. According to [WPF UI persistence in TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082331), the solution would be to use a different `ItemsControl` that looks like a `TabControl`.

Comment: Works for the first issue, using ItemsControl is does not seem to be a good solution for my project. But losing the position is less weird than having synchronized position of scrollbars, so I accept this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the second issue using new control `ZoomPanel : ScrollViewer`, where the position of scollbars is saved according to `DataContext.GetHashCode()`. Maybe not optimal solution, but works for me. Every tab has its own ViewModel, so the position of scrollbars is preserved.

```
public static readonly Dictionary<int, Point> ScrollbarPositions = new Dictionary<int, Point>();

private void ZoomPanelScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ZoomPanel panel = (ZoomPanel)sender;

    // do not save position when uloading or empty data context
    if(!panel.IsLoaded || this.DataContext == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // save scrollbar position
    int dataContextHashCode = this.DataContext.GetHashCode();
    Point position = new Point(panel.HorizontalOffset, panel.VerticalOffset);

    if(ScrollbarPositions.ContainsKey(dataContextHashCode))
    {
        ScrollbarPositions[dataContextHashCode] = position;
    }
    else
    {
        ScrollbarPositions.Add(dataContextHashCode, position);
    }
}

private void ZoomPanelLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.DataContext == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // load scrollbar position
    int dataContextHashCode = this.DataContext.GetHashCode();
    if (ScrollbarPositions.ContainsKey(dataContextHashCode))
    {
        Point position = ScrollbarPositions[dataContextHashCode];
        this.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(position.X);
        this.ScrollToVerticalOffset(position.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that GetHashCode is not guaranteed to be unique. The safest way is to add a unique ID property on your ViewModel or simply save the Scrollbar positions using their index in the control.

Comment: Using index is not an option for me, because I would need to determine the tab index from inner control. Next problem with this approach is that the tab index can be changed by closing and reopening the tab. This is not crucial part of code, just a GUI enhancement, so I'm willing to take a risk with the hash code. Good point with the hash code though - great comment.